# Google Play Rejects My App For Unsafe Cryptographic Encryption Patterns

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, encryption, google-play, publish

I haven't had any issues with the Google Play Store until 4-5 months ago. I've finally gotten back to it, and now all my published Internal/Alpha builds keep getting rejected.

It's a Unity game. I have not included any encryption libraries, nor do I want any Amazon libraries. But the error message says it's a problem with encryption and affects some Amazon library...

The only libraries I use are [Ultimate Mobile Pro](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/integration/ultimate-mobile-pro-130345) and Unity IAP...

Would anyone be able to help?

Thank you.

> Security alert
>
> Your app contains unsafe cryptographic encryption patterns. Please see this Google Help Center article for details.
>
> Vulnerable classes:
>
> com.amazon.insights.validate.EncryptionValidator.validate
> Affects APK version 12.

Comment: What is your unity version?

Comment: Unity IAP may contain hooks for Amazon. See this page: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityIAP.html Are you up-to-date with Unity IAP?

Comment: @0xBFE1A8: I've been on 2019.2.2f1 for several months. I tried upgrading to 2019.2.15f1 (the latest version currently), but am still having the same issue.

Comment: @Topher: Thanks for the suggestion. I'll try deleting UnityIAP completely and see if that solves it.

Comment: @Topher: Quick Update... The Unity IAP was what Google was complaining about. I removed it completely and resubmitted a new Internal Test build, and it was approved. So now I know I'll have to re-import it. Perhaps I won't include the Amazon files for importing, or otherwise. But in the meantime, could you please move your suggestion into its own answer? I know I'll mark it, and eventually add an update with the actual solution or workaround.

Comment: @Topher: Update 2: Indeed, I've uninstalled and re-imported Unity IAP, and now it works fine. Could you type it up as an Answer, that I may mark it? Thanks again.

Comment: @Stout: I'm happy that it worked for you!  I added the answer.  Thanks!

Comment: @Topher: Likewise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unity IAP contains hooks for Amazon.  See this page: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityIAP.html

Are you up-to-date with Unity IAP?

Comment: Indeed, that was it. I've uninstalled and re-imported Unity IAP, and now it works perfectly. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to follow this: https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/9450925 it is well explained and you should be able to solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I'm not doing any kind of encryption whatsoever. I do not see how this code snippet applies to me.